# OpenCL Performance Optimization

Tags: optimization, opencl, gpgpu

I have started learning OpenCL and I currently try to test how much I can improve performance for a simple skeletal animation algorithm. To do this I have written a program that performs skeletal animation from randomly generated vertices and transformation matrices twice, once with an SSE-optimized linear algebra library in plain C++, and once using my own OpenCL kernel on GPU (I'm testing on an Nvidia GTX 460).

I started off with a simple kernel where each work-item transforms exactly one vertex, with all values read from global memory. Because I was not satisfied with the performance of this kernel, I tried to optimize a little. My current kernel looks like this:

```c
inline float4 MultiplyMatrixVector(float16 m, float4 v)
{
    return (float4) (
        dot(m.s048C, v),
        dot(m.s159D, v),
        dot(m.s26AE, v),
        dot(m.s37BF, v)
    );
}


kernel void skelanim(global const float16* boneMats, global const float4* vertices, global const float4* weights, global const uint4* indices, global float4* resVertices)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    int lid = get_local_id(0);

    local float16 lBoneMats[NUM_BONES];
    async_work_group_copy(lBoneMats, boneMats, NUM_BONES, 0);

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_VERTICES_PER_WORK_ITEM ; i++) {
        int vidx = gid*NUM_VERTICES_PER_WORK_ITEM + i;

        float4 vertex = vertices[vidx];
        float4 w = weights[vidx];
        uint4 idx = indices[vidx];

        resVertices[vidx] = (MultiplyMatrixVector(lBoneMats[idx.x], vertex * w.x)
                + MultiplyMatrixVector(lBoneMats[idx.y], vertex * w.y)
                + MultiplyMatrixVector(lBoneMats[idx.z], vertex * w.z)
                + MultiplyMatrixVector(lBoneMats[idx.w], vertex * w.w));
    }
}
```

Now I process a constant number of vertices per work-item, and I prefetch all the bone matrices into local memory only once for each work-item, which I believed would lead to way better performance because the matrices for multiple vertices could be read from the faster local memory afterwards. Unfortunately, this kernel performs worse than my first attempt, and even worse than the CPU-only implementation.

Why is performance so bad with this should-be optimization?

If it helps, here is how I execute the kernel:

```c
#define NUM_BONES 50
#define NUM_VERTICES 30000
#define NUM_VERTICES_PER_WORK_ITEM 100
#define NUM_ANIM_REPEAT 1000

uint64_t PerformOpenCLSkeletalAnimation(Matrix4* boneMats, Vector4* vertices, float* weights, uint32_t* indices, Vector4* resVertices)
{
    File kernelFile("/home/alemariusnexus/test/skelanim.cl");

    char opts[256];
    sprintf(opts, "-D NUM_VERTICES=%u -D NUM_REPEAT=%u -D NUM_BONES=%u -D NUM_VERTICES_PER_WORK_ITEM=%u", NUM_VERTICES, NUM_ANIM_REPEAT, NUM_BONES, NUM_VERTICES_PER_WORK_ITEM);

    cl_program prog = BuildOpenCLProgram(kernelFile, opts);

    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(prog, "skelanim", NULL);

    cl_mem boneMatBuf = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, NUM_BONES*sizeof(Matrix4), boneMats, NULL);
    cl_mem vertexBuf = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, NUM_VERTICES*sizeof(Vector4), vertices, NULL);
    cl_mem weightBuf = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, NUM_VERTICES*4*sizeof(float), weights, NULL);
    cl_mem indexBuf = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, NUM_VERTICES*4*sizeof(uint32_t), indices, NULL);
    cl_mem resVertexBuf = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, NUM_VERTICES*sizeof(Vector4), NULL, NULL);

    uint64_t s, e;
    s = GetTickcount();

    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &boneMatBuf);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &vertexBuf);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &weightBuf);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), &indexBuf);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(cl_mem), &resVertexBuf);

    size_t globalWorkSize[] = { NUM_VERTICES / NUM_VERTICES_PER_WORK_ITEM };
    size_t localWorkSize[] = { NUM_BONES };

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < NUM_ANIM_REPEAT ; i++) {
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cq, kernel, 1, NULL, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
    }

    clEnqueueReadBuffer(cq, resVertexBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, NUM_VERTICES*sizeof(Vector4), resVertices, 0, NULL, NULL);

    e = GetTickcount();

    return e-s;
}
```

I guess there are more things that could be optimized, maybe batching some of the other global reads together, but first I would really like to know why this first optimization didn't work.

Comment: I don't know about the performance, but what you are doing seems to have undefined results. You use an async_copy operation followed by a barrier. The barrier will not wait for the async copy to finish - it will continue as soon as all work items have reached that point. According to the spec, you have to use the wait_group_events function in your kernel after an async_copy, or the results are undefined. This makes sense, because the async_copy is happening while the rest of the kernel is executing, so wait_group_events will force the kernel to make sure that the memory copy is done.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are affecting the performance in your exercise.

1) `OpenCL` conforms to `C99` std that does not contain anything about inline functions, i.e. the clcc compiler either just ignores the `inline` keyword and does a regular call, or it supports the inlining silently. But it is not mandated to support that feature.

So, better define your `MultiplyMatrixVector` as a pre-processor macro. Though this is not a major problem in your case.

2) You incorrectly threat the local memory (the `LDM`).

Although its latency times less than the latency of the `global memory` when it accessed properly, the `local memory` is subject to bank conflicts.

Your vertex index is calculated with stride 100 per work item. The number of banks depends on the GPU in use but usually it is 16 or 32, i.e. you may access up to 16(32) four byte `LDM` variables in one cycle without penalty if all of them are in different banks. Otherwise, you get a `bank conflict` (when two or more threads accesses the same bank) that is serialized.
Your 100 threads in a work group accesses the array in `LDM` with no special arrangement about bank conflicts. Moreover, the array elements are float16, i.e. a single element spans all 16 banks (or half of 32 banks). Thus, you have a bank conflict in each row of `MultiplyMatrixVector` function. The cummulative `degree` that conflict at least 16x32 (here 16 is the number of the vector elements you access and 32 is a size of half wavefront or halfwarp).

The solution here is not to copy that array to `LDM`, but to allocate it in the host with `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY` (which you already did) and declare your kernel using `__constant` specifier for `boneMats` argument.
Then the `OpenCL` library would allocate the memory in the constant area inside `GPU` and the access to that array would be fast:

```
kernel void skelanim(__constant const float16* boneMats, 
                     global const float4* vertices, 
                     global const float4* weights, 
                     global const uint4* indices, 
                     global float4* resVertices)
```

Comment: I don't think your comment about inline is correct, because C99 for sure supports inline functions. See f.e https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/myth-and-reality-about-inline-in-c99/

Answer (score -2):

It looks like EACH thread  in a Work Group is copying  the same 50 floats  before the  computation starts. This will saturate the Global Memory bandwidth.

try this

```
if ( lid == 0 )
{
    async_work_group_copy(lBoneMats, boneMats, NUM_BONES, 0);
}
```

This  does the copy only once  per work group.

Comment: not the case. each work item needs to encounter the async_work_group_copy line with the same params. http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/async_work_group_copy.html